# SAX Parser and XML Schema (XSD) validation

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, sax

Which Java XML libraries can do SAX-based parsing and validation against an XML Schema (XSD) at the same time?

I'm really looking for the most efficient solution for reading **and** validating large XML files.

bonus points if you can provide sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/) which is part of the Sun JDK can do validation.  You can see in the [docs](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/schema.html).

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Robert , Xerces provides SAX-based parsing and XSD validation.

You can checkout example at :

http://www.herongyang.com/XML-Schema/Xerces2-XSD-Validation-with-SAXParser.html