# SAX: XML against XSD validation - how to get incorrect attribute's name

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd, sax

I am using SAX to validate XML against XSD and to parse it. To handle validation issues I use custom ErrorHandler.

The problem is that the only feedback I can get if validation goes wrong is linenumber/columnnumber(in SAXParseException) which specifies the position of tag's opening + tagname.

Is there any way to get the name of the specific attribute if it violates xsd restrictions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SAX Parser and XML Schema (XSD) validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417512/sax-parser-and-xml-schema-xsd-validation)

Comment: @PaulSweatte Thats not a good candidate for a duplicate for this question. (Note that it deserves closing for recommendation.)

Comment: Alexey, did you ever come around to solving this issue? If so, please post an answer.